# How many arcs are needed to divide the line $AB$ into 4 equal parts?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

We have a simple hortizonal straight line $AB$ and we want divide it to 4 equal parts.
So at least how many arcs we need to do that?

Actually we must draw 3 vertical lines that divide the line into 4 equal parts but we need at least 12 arcs to draw 3 vertical equitable lines.
Any ideas?
Options are 5 or 2 or 3 or 4 arcs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of the circles have to be unique.
[image]

Construct $DC$, the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ so that $E$ is the midpoint of $AB$. This uses $2$ circles.

Construct $FG$, the perpendicular bisector of $AE$ so that $J$ is the midpoint of $AE$. This uses $2$ more circles.

Construct $IH$, the perpendicular bisector of $EB$ so that $K$ is the midpoint of $EB$. However, since the left circle has already been constructed, we only need $1$ more circle.

In total, this uses $2+2+1=5$ circles.

Comment: An alternative at the last step is to construct the circle with centre $E$ through $J$, giving $K$. This is still $5$ circles, but the third straight line isn't needed.

Comment: @nickgard Thanks for commenting. Do you think there is a way to use only 4 circles, or less?

Comment: I haven't found one. I can't get beyond $2$ bisections needing $2$ circles each and one final extra circle for $5$ circles total.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $5$ appears to be the answer. I have found some additional examples:

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image: c]