# We have a triangle $ABC$ and we must find the angle $ABO$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

We have a triangle $ABC$ and some information related to:
[image: the triangle]

So I don't know use which rule to find the angle $ABO$.
Options are : $30$ or $35$ or $40$ or $45$ degrees.

Comment: I am not too sure but is seems the answer should be $20^{\circ}$

Comment: @Raptor but there is not any options like what you say!

Comment: It must be 30 35 40 45

Comment: Are you sure $BH$ bisects $AC$?

Comment: No that doesn't

Comment: $BH$ Isn't a staright line @Raptor

Comment: Well, if $BH$ did bisect $AC$ then the angle would have been $20^\circ$. My apologies.

Comment: Okay, but $AH=CH$?

Comment: No. That is not true. There is a triangle namely $BOC$ inside $ABC$. And $OH$ is a vertical line that divides AC to 2 equal parts. Yes AH=CH @Raptor

Comment: If you could wait for some time, I could get onto my computer and provide a complete answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Raptor why not? I am really happy that you respect for any user here! I will check your answer

Comment: We know BC. We know AC. We know Angle BCA. Hence we know full triangle...

Comment: As per my calculator answer should be 40

Comment: Can you answer completely @geekyme?

Comment: That is correct @geekyme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

First off, I would like to apologise for the low quality image.
As $\angle OBC=\angle OCB,$ we conclude that $\triangle OBC$ is isosceles, thus $OB=OC=2$.

Then we use the fact that $\sin \theta= \frac {\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}.$ Thus $\angle ACO= 30^\circ.$

As $AH=CH,$ we conclude that $\triangle OAC$ is isosceles, thus $\angle ACO=\angle CAO=30^\circ$.

Using the fact that the angles in a triangle sum to $180^\circ,$ we find that $\angle BOC=140^\circ$ and $\angle AOC=120^\circ.$

$\therefore \angle ABO=100^\circ$

As $\angle OAC=30^\circ$ and $OH=1, OA=2.$

As both $OB$ and $OA$ are equal to $2,$ $\triangle OAB$ is isosceles and $\angle ABO=\angle BAO=x^\circ$

$x+x+100=180 \implies x=40^\circ$

$\therefore\angle ABO=40^\circ$

Comment: Why did you assume that the BH is not a straight line?

Comment: OP's comments. If $BH$ was straight, then the answer would have been $20^\circ$ which is clearly not an option.

Comment: Good work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks :) $\ $ $\ $

Comment: @Raptor thanks a lot. You helped me with this!

Comment: @Raptor would you take a look at this small geometry puzzle?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970228/how-many-arcs-are-needed-to-divide-the-line-ab-into-4-equal-parts         how can i solve it?

Comment: Toby's answer seems to be the best possible answer.